# 2 cisco 3560 switches (layer3)

Tags: cisco, switch, access-control-list

I would like to create ACL to allow port 22, 80, 443 from outside and drop any other service .
can you please explain to me how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Great explanations here:

http://www.petri.co.il/csc_how_to_use_cisco_ios_access_lists_01.htm

Basically, you want to create an ACL that will have three statements, and apply it to the ingress side of the your external interface. That post pretty much explains it in detail so no need for me to rehash what you can just read.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that switch ACL's are not statefull and you need to consider return traffic from your outgoing requests.